# Switch from mirrored to extended displays

Tags: gnome, xorg, multiple-monitors, 17.10, display

I have multiple monitors and I was using extended display, so I can drag windows from one monitor to the next.

I accidentally pressed some keyboard shortcut and now I have mirrored displays. I want to go back to extended.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are a Gnome 3 user, the hotkey was <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

You can use the hotkey combination to switch back, or go to **Settings->Displays** to reconfigure your setup.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install arandr (`apt-get install arandr`).
2. Launch arandr.
3. Drag screen one next to other.
4. Validate.

Comment: arandr solved my problem with an unrelated issue.  thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Open system settings > displays. For each monitor, turn it off with the on/off slider, then turn it back on. This brought back extended displays.

Comment: Hard to believe, but this seems to be the solution (Ubuntu 20.04).